# Ionic call API with Proxy always return 404

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a problem access API, **url always return External IP :** `http://192.168.**.**:8100`

My API is hosted on local IIS server like this IP `192.168.**.**:3000`

When I debuging project on Android Emulator I see on debug console :

> `Proxy added:/api => http://192.168.**.**:3000/`

I use this method access to api. But my url return always
`192.168.**.**:8100/api/Configurations/GetAppConfiguration` so I get an error 404 because my API IP address use 3000 port.

I added config.xml allow navigation href my API url `http://192.168.**.**:3000` but it did not work.

What is the problem ? What am i missing ?

Thanks you for help…

**GetMethod**

```
getPosts (): Observable<any[]> {
    debugger;
    return this.http.get("api/Configurations/GetAppConfiguration")
        .map(this.parseData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Ionic.config.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.** .** :3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
 "name": "Run Android on emulator",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "ionicLiveReload": true,
            "devServerTimeout": 120000
```

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content original-src="index.html" src="http://192.168.**.**:8100" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />   
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />      
    </platform>
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168. ** . ** :8101" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168. ** . ** :8100" /> 
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screensize" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `return this.http.get("http://192.168.x.x:3000/Configurations/GetAppConfiguration")`

Comment: if ı use directly, I get an error Response with status: 0  for URL: null"

Comment: You declare your proxy on `/api` but youre calling `/Confiruation` thus not using your proxy. Try `/api/Configuration`

Comment: I try /api/Configuration/.. but can not resolve ip. Finally url look like   externalIP/Configuration/... I solve problem and added to answer. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem

Added **ionic.config.json** files my proxies setting like this

```
"proxies": [
      {
          "path": "*/apibase",
          "proxyUrl": "http://192.168. ** . **:3000"
      }
   ]
```

**change Config.xml file and added new configuration property**

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

**use get method like this**

```
getPosts (): Observable<any[]> {        
 return this.http.get("apibase/api/Configurations/GetAppConfiguration")
    .map(this.parseData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

}